# NSMutablearray's last element gets corrupted and becomes standard NSObject from custom object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I run into a weird problem with a NSMutableArray today.
I'm parsing an XML file and I add the parsed items as custom objects. There are 37 items in total.
So, when my view loads, I did this, as a test:

```
[parser loadDataBase];
ProductItem* item = [parser.productDetail.prodItems objectAtIndex:36];
NSLog(@"test 1 %@", item.idItem);
self.product = parser.productDetail;
item = [self.product.prodItems objectAtIndex:36];
NSLog(@"test 2 %@", item.idItem);
[parser release];
```

At this point, everything works just fine. Both NSLog print the correct value for the last item in the mutable array.

The problem is when I try to add these items into a table.
When the app tries to get the item at index 36, to display its properties, instead of a ProductItem custom object, it gets a NSObject object... everything is lost for the last item, being replaced with a mere NSObject.

I do absolutely nothing with the array in that class, or any other class, except the parser.
Everything is ok when it leaves the parser, everything is ok when I read it from the parser, everything is ok when I check to see if I got all the values correctly from the parser. But somehow, the last value gets corrupted after this, even though I don't do anything that might cause this.

Here's the code I use in the cellForRow:

```
NSLog(@"index %i", indexPath.row);
ProductItem* item = [self.product.prodItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell2.itemName.text = item.name;
```

The row is 36, the last one, and boom! EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to read the name property.

Does anyone here have a clue about what might be happening? I never ran into such a problem before
Thank you for your time and attention!

Comment: whether the `product` object has the `retain` property declared in .h file?

Comment: yes, it's nonatomic, retain. Besides, the rest of the items in the array are ok, it's just the last one that gets broken

Comment: just print the array, you can come to know

NSLog(@"Products %@",parser.productDetail.prodItems);

Comment: I already know the content of the array. It's all good, except for the last item, who somehow gets corrupted. There is no need for me to print it... I just need to know what might happen to the last item that only he gets broken, but the others don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from a colleague, I found out what was happening.
I was releasing my currentParsedItem in the parser's dealloc, so everything looked ok before the [parser release]; but after that the, "currentParsedItem" that was the last object in my mutable array was being set to nil in the dealloc function of the parser, and I ended up with a blank NSObject

Hope this tip helps others with a similar problem!